# ansible - iterate all hosts and retrieve data from results

Tags: git, ansible

I want to use ansible to get all the remotes of the git-repositories on a server. On a server there might be a lot of git-repos in a special folder /home/vhosts/cms/ and in each repo there might be multiple remotes for the git-repo. So I want to loop over all hosts and there loop over all git repositories and there get a list over all present remotes.

My problem is the work with the variables and loops in ansible. I can access the repos and retrieve all information from 'git remote -v'. The output looks something like

```
TASK: [debug var=gitremotes] **************************************************
ok: [<host>] => {
    "var": {
        "gitremotes": {
            "changed": true,
            "msg": "All items completed",
            "results": [
                {
                    "changed": true,
                    "cmd": "cd /home/vhosts/cms/customer/html && nice -n 25 git remote -v",
                    "delta": "0:00:00.005960",
                    "end": "2016-01-08 15:10:34.044679",
                    "invocation": {
                        "module_args": "cd /home/vhosts/cms/customer/htm && nice -n 25 git remote -v",
                        "module_complex_args": {},
                        "module_name": "shell"
                    },
                    "item": "customer",
                    "rc": 0,
                    "start": "2016-01-08 15:10:34.038719",
                    "stderr": "",
                    "stdout": "origin\tssh://git.gitserver/customer.git(fetch)\norigin\tssh://git.gitserver/customer.git (push)",
                    "stdout_lines": [
                        "origin\tssh://git.gitserver/customer.git (fetch)",
                        "origin\tssh://git.gitserver/customer.git (push)"
                    ],
                    "warnings": []
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I can access this one stdout_lines but I need to retrieve all gitremotes from all git-repos on all the servers. How would one do that?

What works at the moment is to retrieve all the vhosts and iterate over them.

```
---
- name: get a list of all remotes
  hosts: webservers
  tasks:
  - include: ../roles/webservers/tasks/get_cms_instances.yml
  - name: loop over instances and get git remotes
    shell: cd /home/vhosts/cms/{{ item }}/html && nice -n 25 git remote -v
    with_items: vhosts.stdout_lines
    when: vhosts.rc == 0
    register: gitremotes
  - debug: var=gitremotes
  - debug: var="{{ gitremotes.results[0].stdout_lines[0] }}"
```

What way would you go to retrieve the information?

Thanks in advance,

Timo

Comment: Don't you have the results in `gitremotes` for all hosts?

Comment: It would probably be easier to write a shell script which will print all these remotes and run it using the Ansible `script` module.

Comment: @helloV I think you are correct. But when iterating over the hosts and vhosts I need to extract the information from the gitremotes-variable